# remove xml nodes from xml document

Tags: c#, xml, dom

I have a XMLDocument like:

```
<Folder name="test">
         <Folder name="test2">
              <File>TestFile</File>
         </Folder>
 </Folder>
```

I want only the folder´s, not the files. So, how to delete / manipulate the XML Document in c# to delete / remove ALL  elements in the document?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use `XDocument` and LINQ, you can do

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename) // or XDocument.Parse(string)
doc.Root.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name == "File").Remove();
```

-- edited out an error

Answer (score 4):

To remove a node from an `XMLDocument` (see Jens' answer for remove node form `XDocument`)

```
XmlDocument doc = XmlDocument.Load(filename); // or XmlDocument.LoadXml(string)
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//file");
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes) {
   node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
}
```

Watch for the possible null exception if node.ParentNode is null.